# Resting knight miniboss

Tags: dark-souls-2

In the early area, the forest you will see a knight sleeping under the tree. When can I fight him and what do I get from defeating him?

Answer (score 3):

The knight is a Heide Knight, there are multiple in the game.

You can fight him as soon as you attack him, and he drops The Heide Sword, a faith scaling lightning weapon.

His fight is pretty difficult if you are new to Dark Souls 2, so make sure all the regular enemies are dead and you have sufficiant healing.

http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Heide_Knight